# Python - plotting different coloured clusters using PIL

Tags: python, plot, python-imaging-library, cluster-analysis

I have a few thousand data-points with labels which I'm plotting in gray-scale as an image using PIL (Python Image Library). I'm using the function "render()" available [here](https://github.com/turian/textSNE/blob/master/render.py). I would now also like to pass cluster labels into the function for each point and plot the clusters in different colours. For this I have to generate different colours randomly.

Can someone suggest how I can do this colour generation?

Thanks!

Comment: Colors generally consist of one or more numeric components, like Red, Green, and Blue, or Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Black. You could use the `random` module to generate the number necessary and then use the group to create a color. To avoid repeats, you could store any generated in a dictionary and then use that to make sure succeeding results aren't duplicates of any earlier ones.

Comment: For the moment I'm using pyplot which gives me a decent plot but the labels overlap quite a lot. The grayscale version of render.py looks good.

Answer (score 1):

A nice colour generator is the one Dopplr came up with for city labels:

> We wanted a deterministic RGB colour value
>   for each city. At first, we tried mapping the
>   latitude and longitude of a city to a point in
>   colour space, but we found that this made
>   neighbouring cities too similar in colour. This
>   means that people who travel frequently between Glasgow and Edinburgh wouldn’t
>   clearly see the difference in colour between
>   the two. Also, since so much of the Earth’s
>   surface is covered in water rather than cities,
>   it leads to a sparse use of the potential colour
>   space. In the end, we went with a much simpler approach: we take the MD5 digest of the city’s name, convert it to hex and take the first 6 characters as a CSS RGB value.

From the Dopplr blog, saved by Ian Kennedy.
http://everwas.com/2009/03/dopplr-city-colors.html

This is easy to implement in Python and you can input your label names and get an RGB colour out.

Comment: See also https://optional.is/required/2010/12/13/hls-world-map/ and https://optional.is/required/2011/01/12/maximum-color-contrast/